# Django flatpages aren't registering to create FlatPageSitemap

Tags: django, sitemap, django-flatpages

I can't seem to get flatpages for my site to register, and therefore can't get my sitemap.xml  for flatpages to work either. I have the following files:

settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
    ...
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'django.contrib.flatpages',
    ...
)

SITE_ID = 1
```

urls.py (main urls.py file for the project, my app is named 'shoes'):

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps import FlatPageSitemap

sitemaps = {
    'shoes': FlatPageSitemap
}

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^', include('shoes.urls', namespace='shoes')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap', {'sitemaps': sitemaps}),
)
```

urls.py for my 'shoes' app:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from shoes import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^homepage/$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^detail-page/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
)
```

I've run syncdb but the flatpages section in the admin remains blank, without any entries, and therefore the sitemap doesn't register them. How can I get these flatpages ('home' and 'detail') to register?

Answer (score 0):

Flatpages app are for dynamic creation of flatpages. You can add flatpages in django admin and they will be automatically "added" to urls

When you are using FlatpageFallbackMiddleware flatpages are resolved after all other choices (like views in urls.py) gave 404 response. Then middleware checks urls in database and if it finds match it responds with that page.

You didn't add any flatpages so your db/admin/sitemap doesn't show any.